# Single Database For website and android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have web hosting with 1&1 and want want to create a website that allows me to edit and query the MySql db and also be able to access/query that db from and android app. I know this is possible using JSON and with php. This is what I currently am planing to try to implement, but I am pretty new to programing in general and wonder if this might start to bog down the database.

My question is whether there is a better way to host data for interoperability between apps and websites. Would it be better to eventually run a java server that would connect to the db and have the app connect through the java server instead of app going through the website using php?

Answer (score 0):

Start small and learn the basics. Once you start to learn you'll see what direction YOU need to go in. There is no right or wrong answer to this question.

Comment: So starting with that app connecting with php and jason would be the best way to start small?

Comment: Start by learning PHP and MySQL. You'll get a really good understanding once you do that

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to learn programing off the web and sometimes I have what seem like fairly simple but some what unique questions. I will follow your advice.

Comment: No problem. You'll start to see how the pieces fit together shortly. It's frustrating at first.

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit unclear, but in general, one would usually create a server with a db of your choice, and have the clients (website / android app) connect to it directly. so like relentless said, it sounds like you are getting ahead of yourself, so start small, try to setup a server to perform simple tasks, and see how you can get your web page and app to communicate with it.